# Align all divs to center in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have a dashboard which has many div's.

I need to position all divs to the center when the user re sizes the page as below:

[image]

The HTML for the divs is below:

```
 <div style="min-height: 1000px;text-align:center; position: relative;">
                    <div style="position: relative; min-height: 1000px;">

                        <div id="Steps" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Distance" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Floors" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="ActivityMinutes" class="chartContainer"></div>

                        <div id="Calories" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Weights" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="BMI" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Sleep" class="chartContainer"></div>

                        <div id="Food" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Water" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="BloodPressure" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Glucose" class="chartContainer"></div>

                        <div id="HeartRate" class="chartContainer"></div>
                        <div id="Devices" class="chartContainer"></div>

                    </div>      
                </div>


    .chartContainer {
    width: 280px;    
    height: 240px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2.5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1.5px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T9Fb7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block`

If you're using media-queries, you can just set `float` to `none` at the smaller screen size.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Fb7/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change your `float:left` to `display:inline-block` in `.chartContainer`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Fb7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="min-height: 1000px;text-align:center; position: relative;">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="Steps" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Distance" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Floors" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="ActivityMinutes" class="chartContainer"></div>

        <div id="Calories" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Weights" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="BMI" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Sleep" class="chartContainer"></div>

        <div id="Food" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Water" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="BloodPressure" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Glucose" class="chartContainer"></div>

        <div id="HeartRate" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Devices" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="Friends" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <%--<div id="Other" class="chartContainer"></div>--%>

    </div>      
</div>

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;*Or however much you want.*
    right: 25%;*Or however much you want.*
    min-height: 1000px;
}

.chartContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 280px;    
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2.5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1.5px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```